# Dynamic cachename in service worker

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

I was wondering how I could use a dynamic cacheName?
Basically I want to be able to clear the cache for for a specific url.
So I thought I could create a cache with name formA, formB etc...
and when the form is filled in, I want to clear/delete that cache.

Situation:
I have 2 forms, who have shared css, js and also shared serviceworker etc... But I want to be able to make them offline available. So I want to save them in the cache, like "formA-cache" and "formB-cache", caching the corresponding forms assets.

And when they are filled in, submit them, and clear them from cache.

This is my Service worker for now, using Google Workbox.

```
importScripts(
    "https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/5.1.2/workbox-sw.js"
  );
  
  const { skipWaiting, clientsClaim } = workbox.core;
  const { registerRoute } = workbox.routing;
  const { NetworkFirst } = workbox.strategies;
  
  skipWaiting();
  clientsClaim();
  
  workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([
    "/etc.clientlibs/fd/af/runtime/clientlibs/guideRuntime/resources/images/busy-state.gif",
    "/etc.clientlibs/fd/af/runtime/clientlibs/widgets/numericStepper/resources/images/Minus.svg",
    "/etc.clientlibs/fd/af/runtime/clientlibs/widgets/numericStepper/resources/images/Plus.svg",
    "/etc.clientlibs/fd/rte/gui/components/clientlibs/core/resources/List_a.svg",
    "/etc.clientlibs/fd/rte/gui/components/clientlibs/core/resources/List_ordered.svg",
    "/etc/clientlibs/fd/themes/dev-team-theme/assets/Accordion-Add-Default.svg",
    "/etc/clientlibs/fd/themes/dev-team-theme/assets/Accordion-Delete-Default.svg",
    "/etc/clientlibs/fd/themes/dev-team-theme/assets/Chevron-Active.svg",
    "/etc/clientlibs/fd/themes/dev-team-theme/assets/Chevron-Right-Hover.svg",
    "/etc/clientlibs/fd/themes/dev-team-theme/assets/Chevron-Right-White.svg",
    "/etc/clientlibs/fd/themes/dev-team-theme/assets/Minus.svg",
    "/etc/clientlibs/fd/themes/dev-team-theme/assets/Minus_Hover.svg",
    "/etc/clientlibs/fd/themes/dev-team-theme/assets/Plus.svg",
    "/etc/clientlibs/fd/themes/dev-team-theme/assets/Plus_Hover.svg",
    "/etc/clientlibs/fd/themes/dev-team-theme/assets/Save.svg",
    "/etc/clientlibs/fd/themes/dev-team-theme/assets/Submit-Hover.svg",
    "/etc/clientlibs/fd/themes/dev-team-theme/assets/Table-Edit-Default.svg",
  ]);
  
  registerRoute(
    ({ request }) => {
      console.log("    ", request.url);
      return (
        request.destination === "iframe" ||
        request.destination === "document" ||
        request.destination === "image" ||
        request.destination === "script" ||
        request.destination === "style" ||
        request.destination === "font"
      );
    },
    new NetworkFirst({
      cacheName: "abc-forms", // This needs to become formA-cache, formB-cache etc...
    })
  );
```

Any help or ideas are welcome!

Thanks

Mario

Answer (score 0):

While you could create a named cache for all URLs, I would not advise this. Instead write a cache invalidation routine to purge the cached version and replace with the new one.

As long as you know what named cache it is in then you can just cache the new version and it will replace the old version.

If you do not know what named cache the response is cached then you will need to loop over all named caches to see if the response if cached to do that. Basically find the target named cache.